# Rmarkdown to html can't make the footer full width

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I'm using the yaml below in Rmarkdown to create a table of contents as well as a header and footer, but the footer does not render as the full width of the page.  It is the full width of the body of the document.  How do I force the footer to be full width of the page?  Do I need to change something in the css file?

```
output:
  html_document: 
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    theme: lumen
    css: stylesheets/common.css
    includes: 
      in_header: header.html
      after_body: footer.html
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] flexdashboard_0.5.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1   rsconnect_0.8.15 htmltools_0.4.0  tools_3.6.1      yaml_2.2.0      
 [6] Rcpp_1.0.3       rmarkdown_1.17   knitr_1.26       jsonlite_1.6     xfun_0.11       
[11] digest_0.6.22    packrat_0.5.0    rlang_0.4.1      evaluate_0.14
```

Here is the footer.html

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="tmp-container">
        <!-- .footer-wrap -->
            <!-- .footer-doi -->
            <div class="footer-doi">
                <!-- footer nav links -->
                <ul class="menu nav">
                    <li class="first leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.doi.gov/privacy">DOI Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.usgs.gov/laws/policies_notices.html">Legal</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www2.usgs.gov/laws/accessibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.usgs.gov/sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
                    <li class="last leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://answers.usgs.gov/">Contact USGS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!--/ footer nav links -->      
            </div>
            <!-- /.footer-doi -->

            <hr>

        <!-- .footer-utl-links -->
        <div class="footer-doi">
            <ul class="menu nav">
                <li class="first leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.doi.gov/">U.S. Department of the Interior</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.doioig.gov/">DOI Inspector General</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.whitehouse.gov/">White House</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/management/egov/">E-gov</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www.doi.gov/pmb/eeo/no-fear-act">No Fear Act</a></li>
                <li class="last leaf menu-links menu-level-1"><a href="https://www2.usgs.gov/foia">FOIA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>          
        <!-- /.footer-utl-links -->
        <!-- .footer-social-links -->
        <div class="footer-social-links">
            <ul class="social">
                <li class="follow">Follow</li>
                <li class="twitter">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/usgs" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"><span class="only">Twitter</span></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="facebook">
                    <a href="https://facebook.com/usgeologicalsurvey" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"><span class="only">Facebook</span></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="github">
                    <a href="https://github.com/usgs" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-github"><span class="only">GitHub</span></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="flickr">
                    <a href="https://flickr.com/usgeologicalsurvey" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-flickr"><span class="only">Flickr</span></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="youtube">
                    <a href="http://youtube.com/usgs" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"><span class="only">YouTube</span></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="instagram">
                    <a href="https://instagram.com/usgs" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram"><span class="only">Instagram</span></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.footer-social-links -->
    </div>
        <!-- /.footer-wrap -->  
</footer>
<!-- END USGS Footer Template- -->
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TKQR8KP"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Here is the footer section of the css

```
/* footer (only) css */

.menu.nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav:before, .nav:after {
   content: none;
}
footer.footer {
    background: #00264c;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

footer.footer .footer-doi {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

footer.footer .footer-doi ul.menu li a {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}

footer.footer .footer-doi ul.menu li:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

footer.footer .footer-doi ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

footer.footer .footer-doi ul.menu li:after {
    content: "|";
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

footer.footer .footer-doi ul.menu li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}

footer.footer .footer-wrap .menu.nav a {
    padding: 4px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}

footer.footer .footer-social-links {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 0;
}

footer.footer .footer-social-links ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

footer.footer .footer-social-links ul li.follow {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

footer.footer .footer-social-links ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

footer.footer .footer-social-links ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

footer.footer .footer-social-links ul li a i {
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: We don't know the content of the footer as well as the stylesheet. Some CSS might fix this, but it is hard to answer.

Comment: Added the footer.html and the footer section of the css